# PHP type hinting - code vs. annotations

Tags: php, phpdoc, type-hinting

PHP 5 can do some (limited) [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), however, it seems to me that in real-world projects, types are usually described in doc comments. For example, instead of this:

```
/**
 * Test method
 */
function test(SomeType $param1) {
    ...
}
```

there will more commonly be

```
/**
 * Test method
 *
 * @param SomeType param1
 */
function test($param1) {
    ...
}
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of the two approaches? And if I'm right in the assumption that the PhpDoc method is more common, why is that? Why don't people utilize the built-in language feature more?

**Edit**: the third option is to use both approaches combined:

```
/**
 * Test method
 *
 * @param SomeType param1
 */
function test(SomeType $param1) {
    ...
}
```

However, I personally haven't seen this used too often (looked at libraries like Symfony or PHPUnit) and this also seems like doing some work for not much additional benefit to be honest. Maybe that's why it isn't seen more often.

Comment: In the first, you can wirte `@param SomeType $param1` also. And it prevents you to pass any other type of type than `SomeType`. Second will only show you it in the phpDoc, but `$param1` could be any type.

Comment: Good point, I've updated the OP.

Comment: If you're using an IDE with auto complete, you can also type hint inline, which comes in handy from time to time: /* @var $somevar \YourNamespace\YourObject */

Comment: For the record: PHP has evolved. Its newer versions have much more powerful hinting capacities (can do scalars, arrays return types, nulls...).

Answer (score 5):

First thing: PHP typehints have different ability to hint than PHPDoc. Differences are (at least):

- Scalar types. Before PHP 7.1, you can not hint scalar types, while nothing prevents you from hinting

  ```
  /**
   * @param string $param Param description
   */
  ```
- Array of hinting. In PHPDoc you can hint, that parameter (or return value) is array of something. It would be:

  ```
  /**
   * @param ClassName[] $param Param description
   */
  ```

  and meaning of this is - array of instances of `ClassName`. This is extremely useful when it comes to return type (because IDE then may do substitutions for methods on iteration of that array, and, therefore, you'll know that you're doing correct thing or not). However, in PHP you can only typehint it as

  ```
  function functionName(array $param) { /*...*/ }
  ```

  so it won't be possible to realize what are actual elements of array. For your information there is a corresponding [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arrayof) for typehinting as array of some elements, which is currently rejected - but may be in future such possibility will appear in PHP.

But, on the other hand, using PHP typehints is still different thing and normally you should do both - so, if it's possible to hint somehow in PHP (like for array sample above) - do it, and add PHPDoc block as well. PHP typehint allows you to enforce behavior on language level, while PHPDoc is only "information" source, it serves only information goal and can not prevent of passing illegal argument type.

Comment: Good points, I'm just not sure about the last paragraph. While theoretically it certainly feels better to have both types of type hints it doesn't probably add too much value in practice, at least that's the way I see it and if you look at real-world projects out there it seems that I am not alone.

Comment: But it adds. If you have array of some instances, you will typehint it in PHP and in PHPDoc, so you, at least, won't be able to pass non-array to function (on language level), and, on the other hand, you'll be able to use IDE substitutions. So - yes, PHP typehints are limited, but you should use them as much as it's possible to narrow incoming parameter type, if you know the context of that

Comment: Actual enforcement of types *at execution time* is the reason to put typehints in the code itself.  Putting it in the PHPDoc is common practice, mostly because PHPDoc *predates* PHP typehinting, and thus having a type *documented* by PHPDoc was the best you could do way back then with regard to a user knowing what the code expects.  Doc generators will usually presume that the PHPDoc info is The True Info and use it, though they will also fall back to the code itself if PHPDoc is not given.  IDEs usually follow the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use both.

First option is good for controling what objects are you passing to the method. Second usually can be added automaticaly by any modern IDE and it makes your code more readable.